# Why my program is not responding after I want to show it?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, trayicon, systray

I've made a small program with PyQT5 and SysTrayIcon (infi.systray), and if the program is closed (person pressed "X"), there is an option to open it with TrayIcon.

[image]

If the button "Open" pressed (in TrayIcon"), then the program must show as it was at the beginning

[image]

however, it is starting but not responding

[image]

Why? And how to fix it?
My code:

```
import sys
from infi.systray import SysTrayIcon
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(555,333)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(555, 333))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(555, 333))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(555, 333))
        self.centralwidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(555, 333))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Comfortaa")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.centralwidget.setFont(font)
        self.centralwidget.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(150, 2, 255, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 0, 230, 255));")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
# Logo
        self.logo = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.logo.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 30, 201, 221))
        self.logo.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));")
        self.logo.setText("")
        self.logo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("/photos/logo.png"))
        self.logo.setObjectName("logo")
# Rules
        self.Rules = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Rules.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 30, 300, 200))
        self.Rules.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));\n"
"font: 25 10pt \"Comfortaa\";")
        self.Rules.setWordWrap(True)
        self.Rules.setObjectName("Rules")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)


        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)



# Trayicon
        def open(systray):
            MainWindow.show()
        def info(systray):
            print("Info")
        def help(systray):
            print("Help")
        menu_options = (("Open", None, open), ("Info", None, info),("Help", None, help))
        systray = SysTrayIcon("/icons/logo.ico", "App", menu_options)
        systray.start()


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Program"))
        self.Rules.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Short rules how to use it:"))




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app_icon = QtGui.QIcon()
    app_icon.addFile('/icons/logo.ico')
    app.setWindowIcon(app_icon)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I don't know what that systray actually does, but it's possible that it's blocking OR that it doesn't work well with the Qt main thread. Since Qt already provides such a feature with [QSystemTrayIcon](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsystemtrayicon.html), I strongly suggest to use that instead of relying on other libraries.

Comment: By default, QApplication quits when the last window is closed. To prevent this you need to set `app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)`

Comment: Also, you really should **not** edit the files generated with `pyuic`, as they are intended to be used as imported modules *only*. Read more about the correct ways to use them in the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: @musicamante I tried it, but I was unable to quit (exit) program, Also I don't know how to print text with PyQT tray icon

Comment: @Heike at the end?

Comment: @AlexZab Are you referring to the QSystemTrayIcon? If that's so, create a new question about it. The `setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)` must be set *before* calling `app.exec_()`.

Comment: @musicamante No, I'm not referring to the QSystemTrayIcon. Thank You

Comment: @AlexZab ok, so what were you referring to? And what do you mean by "I don't know how to print text with PyQT tray icon"?

Comment: @Heike, Thank You very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)` at the end, so your code will look like:

```
import sys
from infi.systray import SysTrayIcon
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(555,333)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(555, 333))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(555, 333))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(555, 333))
        self.centralwidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(555, 333))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Comfortaa")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.centralwidget.setFont(font)
        self.centralwidget.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(150, 2, 255, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 0, 230, 255));")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
# Logo
        self.Elsi_logo = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Elsi_logo.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 30, 201, 221))
        self.Elsi_logo.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));")
        self.Elsi_logo.setText("")
        self.Elsi_logo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("/photos/logo.png"))
        self.Elsi_logo.setObjectName("logo")
# Rules
        self.Rules = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Rules.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 30, 300, 200))
        self.Rules.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));\n"
"font: 25 10pt \"Comfortaa\";")
        self.Rules.setWordWrap(True)
        self.Rules.setObjectName("Rules")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)


        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)



# Trayicon
        def open(systray):
            MainWindow.show()
        def info(systray):
            print("Info")
        def help(systray):
            print("Help")
        menu_options = (("Open", None, open), ("Info", None, info),("Help", None, help))
        systray = SysTrayIcon("/icons/logo.ico", "App", menu_options)
        systray.start()


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Program"))
        self.Rules.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Short rules how to use it:"))




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app_icon = QtGui.QIcon()
    app_icon.addFile('/icons/logo.ico')
    app.setWindowIcon(app_icon)
    app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```